# Gradle: publishApkProductionRelease to internal test

Tags: android, gradle, gradle-play-publisher

I can not publishing a version for the track "internal" on [Gradle Play Publisher](https://github.com/Triple-T/gradle-play-publisher#specify-the-track), my plugin is updated and I am using the latest version of gradle (4.9). What am I doing wrong?

```
play {
    track = 'internal'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved:

My version of Gradle Play Publisher was wrong.